# Временная шкала от начальной даты до конечной

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Всём привет стоит задача получить массив всех дней и месяцев в промежутке между двумя датам  как в диограма Ганта можно ли это сделать при помощи moment Js ? Просто надо вывески  дни и месяцы в одну линию по оси x   Спасибо большое за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вот, например, массив всех дней:

```js
let start = new Date('2019-01-25');
let end = new Date('2019-03-05');
let days = [];

for (let cur = start; cur <= end; cur.setDate(cur.getDate() + 1)) {
  days.push({
    day: cur.getDate(),
    month: cur.getMonth() + 1
  });
}
console.log(days);
```

UPD: Добавлен `month`

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Я изначально намеренно не стал делать месяц, потому что слишком много разных вариантов, в каком именно виде его  будет удобнее использовать (в том же массиве - в отдельном массиве, номера месяцев - их названия, и т.п.). Но пусть будет так, как пример. :)

Comment: Понимаю, просто добавил что бы был пример, а кастомизация уже не займет много времени.